# GLSurfaceView.Renderer - Cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android, interface, opengl-es-2.0, glsurfaceview

I've got a problem, I'm trying to implement the GLSurfaceView.Renderer interface but I can't get it to work. I am importing the android.opengl.GLSurfaceView but it still can't be resolved to a type.

I'm including the code of my class here below.

```
package se.mima.opengl20test;

import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;

public class MyGL20Renderer implements GLSurfaceview.Renderer{

}
```

I just don't get it, shouldn't this work?

Comment: Which API are you developing on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GLSurface**V**iew.Renderer, not GLSurface**v**iew.

Comment: @Tim: I want to put the Touch Listener in this class then how it is possible ?

Comment: @iDroidExplorer - Comments are not an appropriate place to ask new questions. Please create a question if you need help.